# Turning mysql subquery into Join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm new to mysql & just started learning it. Last night I was trying to re-form following sub-query on country table of world database, into a join.

```
SELECT continent, NAME, population FROM country c WHERE
population = (SELECT MAX(population) FROM country c2 
WHERE c.continent=c2.continent AND population > 0)
```

I tried following query and several others with inner join etc. but failed. I'm getting result with the following query where max population is as expected but continent & country name as different.

```
SELECT c.continent, c2.name, MAX(c2.population) AS pop FROM country  c, country c2 
WHERE c.continent = c2.continent GROUP BY continent
```

Please help, how can I get same result as the sub-query above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `MAX(population)` with `GROUP BY continent` inside a subquery, then `JOIN` it with the table itself; Like this:

```
SELECT c1.continent, c1.NAME, c1.population 
FROM country c1 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT continent, MAX(population) AS Maxp
   FROM country
   WHERE population > 0
   GROUP BY continent
) AS c2  ON c1.population = c2.maxp 
        AND c1.continent  = c2.continent;
```